# When two std::map objects are identical

Tags: c++, dictionary, equality

I have two `std::map` objects that I populate with the same data but the order is different:

```
using TMap = std::map<int, std::wstring>;
using TSourceData = std::vector< std::pair<int, std::wstring> >;

TSourceData gen_source_data(int size)
{
    TSourceData result;
    result.reserve(size);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        result.push_back( std::make_pair(i, std::to_wstring(i)) );
    }

    return result;
}

TMap fill_map(const TSourceData& source)
{
    TMap result;

    auto randomized = source;
    std::random_shuffle(randomized.begin(), randomized.end());

    for(const auto &e : randomized)
    {
        result[e.first] = e.second;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto source = gen_source_data(1000);

    auto m1 = fill_map(source);
    auto m2 = fill_map(source);

    std::wcout << (m1 == m2) << std::endl;
}
```

In VS2017 it seems to always print `1` so the two maps are equal no matter in what order they were filled. But is it guaranteed to be so? And if so, could you explain why?

Comment: That's how a `std::map` works, it orders the elements to be able to look them up in O(log(n)) time. `std::unordered_map` on the other hand does not order the elements, but looks them up using a hash.

Comment: @alain Interestingly enough, using `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::map` does not change anything, they are still equal

Comment: fwiw, the order in the two maps is identical. You could have choosen the maps to sort the elements differerntly via the third template parameter

Comment: @FrankGoods, the `operator==` for an `unordered_map` compares the contents of the maps. Order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::map` is an associative container. The difference between a sequential container and an associative container is that:

- a [sequential container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_(C%2B%2B)) lets you decide the position of the element
- an [associative container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_containers) itself determines the position of the element

Also since `std::map` is a sorted container, there can be only one possible order for all the keys, so in the absence of duplicates, insertion order for `std::map` doesn't matter. Similarly, the ordering inside `std::unordered_map` is determined by the hash of each key, and is again not dependent on the insertion order.

Notice that you shuffle a `vector` (a sequential container), then you copy the values into a `map`. It's impossible to "shuffle" a `map`, since you do not control the position of the elements there.

Answer (score 3):

> ... so the two maps are equal no matter in what order they were filled. But is it guaranteed to be so?

Yes, because `std::map` is a  sorted associative container (usually implemented as a binary tree) its elements are guaranteed to be sorted (regardless of its implementation).

Comment: Ok, so all that rotations in binary tree will produce the exact same data structure in the end?

Comment: What ever happens under the hood they will work the same way.  One of the things that'll work the same way is equality comparisons. If you think about it, they wouldn't be very useful as maps otherwise.

Comment: @FrankGoods It's not about the data structure. It's about the requirements. The requirements are that iterating start-to-end of a map gives you a sorted view. That's it.

Comment: @FrankGoods You might want to take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal , in particular *in-order* transversal. This will always produce the values within the tree in the same order, that is in their sorted order, no matter how the actual underlying tree is shaped (as long as it is a valid binary sorting tree). Or maybe to put it in practical words: instead of calling `std::sort`, you could insert items in a map (using only keys) and then get them in order simply by using a for-each on the map (`std::sort` is more efficient though).